# Random walk probability non-symmetric steps

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

I currently have a probability class tutorial question that I have no idea where to begin. At first instinct, I thought it may have been a CTMC question or branching question, but now I have no idea, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Question:

> A node goes down $1$ step with probability $p$ and up $t$ steps with probability $1-p$.
>
> Let $X_n=Y_1+\ldots +Y_n$ where $(Y_n)$ is i.i.d with $P(Y_1 = -1) = p$ and $P(Y_1 = t ) = 1-p$.
>
> Assuming that at $n=0$ the node is at $0$,
>
> a) find $P(X_n = 0)$.
>
> b) find a simple sequence $(u(n))$ such that $P(X_{(t+1)n} = 0) \sim u(n)$.

---

I know that if $p=0$ or $p=1$ then the answer to a) is 0. I have trouble with the case $0<p<1$.
I've also worked out that if the node takes $t$ steps up, then it must take $t$ steps back as well to get to the initial point.
And I am not sure as well, but I think we can use the $\phi (u)$ formula.

Comment: Is $X_n$ defined as the product of the $Y_i$? If so, can $X_n$ even equal 0, unless $k=0$?

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to be sum! I fixed it now :)

Answer (score 1):

That $X_n=0$ means that there was $i$ steps $+t$ and $n-i$ steps $-1$ with $+t\cdot i-1\cdot(n-i)=0$, that is, $i=n/(t+1)$. Hence $P[X_n=0]=0$ if $n$ is not a multiple of $t+1$ and, for every $n\geqslant0$,
$$
P[X_{(t+1)n}=0]={(t+1)n\choose n}(1-p)^np^{tn}.
$$
Stirling's formula yields that, when $n\to\infty$,
$$
P[X_{(t+1)n}=0]\sim\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}\vartheta^n,
$$
with
$$
c=\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{t+1}t},\qquad
\vartheta=(t+1)^{t+1}t^{-t}(1-p)p^t.
$$
Note that $\vartheta=1$ if $p=t/(t+1)$ (this is the zero drift case) and $\vartheta\lt1$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Did! I highly appreciate it!
I can see now that you need t+1 steps for it to not equal 0! that was the part i was having trouble coming up with! thank you heaps!

Comment: With part b) I was just wondering how you came up with that formula, because I was given 
as n goes to infinity,    $frac({n!}/{(root(2pi)n^n+1/2) e^-n)$
(or the following formulaon line 2)
http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/sequence/stirling/stirling.html

Comment: Apply Stirling three times, once for each factorial in the binomial coefficient.